# Flutter - Any way to integrate full story in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, fullstory

I want to integrate [full story](https://www.fullstory.com/mobile-apps/) for my flutter app. I don't see any full story plugin available for flutter. Any way to integrate it into my flutter app without going through the native code base?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can only integrate it with native iOS and Android app. You could try to implement it for both platforms, following their API documentation for each platform. (But this is in my opinion overkill.)

I would suggest using firebase with [firebase_analytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics) and [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics) plugins instead.